# Need to Pass Data From Drop Down List to Table using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Completely stumped with this one, and not even sure it's possible, but if anyone can help, Stack Overflow can.

Right, I've got table

```
<table id="namedConsultants" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Consultant</th>
        <th>Days Assigned</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="ConID" class="form-control" readonly value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ConFullName" class="form-control" readonly value="Person A" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ConTimeAssigned" class="form-control" readonly value="1.0" /></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="editConsultant">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="ConID" class="form-control" readonly value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ConFullName" class="form-control" readonly value="Person B" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ConTimeAssigned" class="form-control" readonly value="2.0" /></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="editConsultant">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When the 'Edit' link is clicked beside a table row, the values **ConID** (hidden) and **ConTimeAssigned** are passed to a JQuery function which then passes them into two drop down lists, **ConsultantID** and **daysAssigned**.

```
<select id="ConsultantID" name="ConsultantID">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>

<select id="daysAssigned" name="daysAssigned">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>


$("#namedConsultants").on('click', '.editConsultant', function () {

    //alert("test");
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var conID = tr.find("input[name=ConID]").val();
    var timeAssigned = tr.find("input[name=ConTimeAssigned]").val();

    $("#ConsultantID").val(conID);
    $("#daysAssigned").val(timeAssigned);

});
```

This all works. Now, at this stage the user can then update the days assigned to the consultant they have clicked on to Edit. The days assigned is a drop down list with list items from 1 to 300.

When the user selects the new value in the days drop down list, they can then click an Update button, which will then update the consultants **ConTimeAssigned** in the table **namedConsultants**.

```
$("#btnUpdateConsultant").click(function (e) {

    var consultantID = $("#ConsultantID").val();
    var newDays = $("#daysAssigned").val();

    alert(newDays);

    e.preventDefault(); 

});
```

There is no database activity here, this is purely an attempt to get data from a table row, pass it into a drop down list, change the value, then pass it back into the table row again.

As I say, I really don't know how to go about this, and any help or advice would be greatly appreciated with this one.

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you cache the `tr` you're currently editing, something like:

```
var editedTr = null;
$(".editConsultant").on("click", function(e) { 
   editedTr = $(this).closest("tr");
   // do the rest of your stuff ...
});
```

Then when you save:

```
$("#btnUpdateConsultant").on("click", function(e) { 
    if(editedTr !== null && editedTr !== "undefined") { 
        // do some validation or whatever ...
        editedTr.find("input[name=ConTimeAssigned]").val(daysAssigned.val());
    }
});
```

I tried preparing a very simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WTxNG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've almost done it already with for example this line:

```
var timeAssigned = tr.find("input[name=ConTimeAssigned]").val();
```

This is fetching the value, but if you modify it a bit:

```
tr.find("input[name=ConTimeAssigned]").val(newVal);
```

It's not inputting a value.

So is your problem finding the correct cell or... ?

Update:

So you have this line:

```
var conID = tr.find("input[name=ConID]").val();
```

Add this after it:

```
var conIDelement = tr.find("input[name=ConID]");
```

And now when you want to change it with updated value you can do:

```
$(conIDelement).val(newVal);
```

Comment: Yes, I can get the new value from the drop down list easily enough, but my problem is finding the correct cell to place the new value.

Comment: Save the elements as well when you click edit. Just leave the val() out from var conID = tr.find("input[name=ConID]").val(); and you can now put the updated stuff to $(conID).val(); Ehh ... I'll update my post.